# Why "Skaffold" creates two images for each Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-10, docker-desktop, skaffold

This is my `skaffild.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: tester/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
    - image: tester/ticketing-client
      context: client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: '**/*.js'
            dest: .
    - image: tester/tickets
      context: tickets
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
    - image: tester/orders
      context: orders
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

And this is one of the `Dockerfile`s for example:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=prod
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I am using `Docker-Desktop` on Windows 10 locally. When I run `skaffold dev` command it creates two instance of each image, one with `latest` tag and the other one with a tag like `66fd1b7d90526513591c1af211f26c9d19d1c7415baac331246219a40a8e6ec0`.

Is it normal? Why does it do that?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your [`tagPolicy`](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/taggers/#sha256-uses-latest-to-tag-images) is set to `sha256`, which tags your docker image twice, once with the sha digest `:66fd1b...` and again with `:latest`. Bit strange because your skaffold.yaml isn't explicitly setting the `tagPolicy` and the default is `gitCommit`.